# Joins - Updating SQL

Tags: mysql

I need to submit an update query in to two tables.

I need to put `'title'` in my `sub_menu` table under the field of `title`.

And I need to put `'id'` in `root_sub` table, under the field of `id`.

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Add more information. Show your tables, show what you want, ...and what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, example at:

http://richardjh.org/blog/update-multiple-mysql-tables-in-one-update-statement/

Answer (score 0):

Update the main table, get the ID of the row and use it for a second update.

Comment: You cannot update information from multiple tables at the same time.

Comment: (except within the context of a transaction)